# Python: Why Result2.txt not generating?

Tags: python

I am stuck at problem while writing detection script subproblem which can calculate total number of seconds an (class)object was in frame.

For example if a class object lets say `dog` was detected in video frame from that time i have to count till the `dog` leaves the frame of video.

For that I am using an detection script which is giving me every second prediction of the class from an float tensor `c` and getting reference from its labelmap gives me class name as `names[int(c)]`.

The `names` will be look like `names=['dog','cat','bigcats','insects']` and `c` in tensor gives class_id as float

So it is pretty simple I am getting detection of object every seconds
now the task is calculate for how many seconds it was exactly there for that I am writing below code

```
#file generate function
import time
def gen_result2(total_time,cl):
 with open('result2.txt','a') as res:
  res.write(cl[-1]) # accessing last valued of class
  res.write('   '+total_time)  # total time already calculated below(final-start)
  res.write('\n')
  res.close()
 return res

#file
cl=[] #class list
tl=[] #timestamp list


#c is below a tensor by which we getting class converting to int to see reference from `name`
class_val=f"{names[int(c)]}" 

# if detected class is None one for white space another for tab
if class_val!=' ' or class_val!=' ': 
 if class_val not in cl: #cl is keeping record of if classes already been detected
  if len(cl)==0:
    cl.append(class_val)
  else:
    # it enters here means a new class is dominating the frame now summing up previous class time
    first_val=tl[0]
    last_val=tl[-1]
    total_time=last_val-first_val
    total_time=time.ctime(total_time) # converting to readable format
    total_time=total_time[12:20] # slicing it down to get only time part(00:00:00)
    tl.clear()
    gen_result2(total_time,cl)
    cl.append(class_val)
else:              
 tym=time.time() # if class already present marking the timestamp at every detection
 print(tym)
 tl.append(tym)  # storing them to list in order to further calculate total_time
 cl.append(class_val)
 cl=set(cl) # converting to set to dump all duplicates
 cl=list(cl) # again conversion to original data type
```

As you can see the code is made to mark each timestamp with their relative class and provide summary in `result2.txt` but as a result no file is generating

[find result2.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyE7Y.png)

It may be issue of the I have used functions but the code management made me to do so if you have an easy implementation to mimic this or any suggestion please comment below so i can know

Comment: How do you know the file isn't created?  Are you sure you're looking in the right directory?

Comment: @JohnGordon becaue i have execuated it multiple times and not even once file `result2.txt` was there & yes it is in the same directory

Comment: Also, the file is created in the `gen_result()` function, which is only called under specific circumstances.  Are you sure it is ever actually called?

Comment: Are you looking in the same directory as the python code file?  That's not necessarily where the file would be created.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes the gen_result() is for when a new class dominates the frame so summing up timestamp of preivous class in total_time and then clearing the timestamplist `tl`

Comment: @JohnGordon i am not sure but i am also locating it with command it is even unable to locate the file

Comment: @JohnGordon this is proof https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyE7Y.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you positive that the code actually ever enters the "else" statement where gen_result2() gets called?

The fact that the file never gets created suggests you may not ever be executing that block of code.

You could try printing/logging a message such as "Wrote total time to file" after calling gen_result2(), to tell you if your code ever gets here.

Also, you are returning res at the end of gen_result2(), but is not clear why you do this.  When you call gen_result2() you are not setting the returned value equal to anything.